# docker-compose build with deep image name hangs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have had a problem with a docker-compose setup that renders it unusable:

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  something:
    image: someone/a.b.c.d
    build:
      context: .
```

When I would then run docker-compose build, it would then freeze forever (or as long as my patience lasted, more than 15min)

It seems that changing the image name to

```
    image: someone/a.b:c.d
```

would fix it.

Was my first version wrong? What is actually the convention for the image name?

Thanks

Comment: If you set `image` and `build`, I think docker compose will try to run the image first, if not found it will try to build the image using your context. Now, docker will tar the context and send it to the docker daemon. If you have lots of files or huge ones, it will take a while. Maybe that's your issue

Comment: About your image, you should put the tag (after colon), by default it's assumed to be `latest`

Comment: @charli. thanks, thats actually the behavior I want. But the problem is not related to the size of the context as the only difference is the name/tag of the image

Comment: Try to run the image as `docker run someone/a.b.c.d`, is it doing something? Also, check your local images with `docker images`, I guess you have `someone/a.b` tagged with `c.d` but you don't have `someone/a.b.c.d`

Answer (score 0):

**update:**

The name seems valid as per the documentation and its working fine under docker-compose version `docker-compose version 1.22.0`

Also no issue with docker build

```
docker build -t someone/a.b.c.d .
```

check your docker-compose version .

> Extended description
>   An image name is made up of slash-separated name components, optionally prefixed by a registry hostname. The hostname must comply with standard DNS rules, but may not contain underscores. If a hostname is present, it may optionally be followed by a port number in the format :8080. If not present, the command uses Docker’s public registry located at registry-1.docker.io by default. Name components may contain lowercase letters, digits and separators. A separator is defined as a period, one or two underscores, or one or more dashes. A name component may not start or end with a separator.
>
> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The fact is, Im using the latest version of everything (docker, docker-compose) and it is not a problem of large context because the behavior is different depending only on where the colon is. I dont really like to let it got just by changing the name of my image, altough it lets me progress at least

Comment: were you able to fix at your end or is context was enough to take such huge time?